# Is it safe to pass user input through rails gsub?

Tags: denial-of-service, rails, regex

Are there risks associated with using [`gsub`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) on user input? Can it be used for [regular expression DoS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS)?

Comment: Is there anything in particular you are worrid about? I think it should be safe, but what comes out on the other side should still be considered untrusted user input.

Comment: I guess DoS kind of things https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: Ah, I did not think of the DOS potential. Good point. I have edited your question to include that angle, feel free to roll back if you dislike the edit.